# ExtJS: Unable to upgrade Sencha cmd

Tags: extjs4, extjs5

I have to create a project in ExtJS5. Right now I am using ExtJs4.2.1 and the Sencha cmd version is 3.1.2.342 I wanted to upgrade it to the latest version. For this, I created a folder and copied ext folder(the ExtJS SDK) into this folder. From my application's ext folder I ran 'sencha upgrade' command. When I check the version it is still showing 3.1.2.342

What steps am I missing? When I try to build the app the error message displays "No compatible version detected". This shows that the cmd version I have can not be used with ExtJS5. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1st, select the path of your application:

```
cd /xampp/htdocs/yourapp //if you are using xampp 
sencha app upgrade [ path-to-new-framework/verison-of-your-sdk ]
```

Comment: Neither am I using xampp nor do I want to upgrade my app. I want to upgrade "sencha cmd" so that I can build my first ExtJS5 application.